# Null check condition in Where clause

Tags: sql-server, null, case, where

```
DECLARE @SubDesc1 nvarchar(100)   
SET @SubDesc1 = null
```

I would like to do something like that.

Query 1

```
SELECT * 
From Table1   
where Category = 'Category1'   
  AND [Description] ='ABC'   
  AND SubDescription1 IS NULL   
   OR SubDescription1 = @SubDesc1
```

Query 2

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1   
WHERE Category = 'Category1'   
  AND [Description] ='ABC'  
  AND SubDescription1 = (Case WHEN @SubDesc1 IS NOT NULL 
                              Then @SubDesc1
                              ELSE SubDescription1 
                              END)
```

None of them solved if my `@SubDesc1 = 'def'`

However, it will get me both records where `SubDescription1 Is null` and `SubDescription1 = 'def'`

How can I do this?

Comment: *AND SubDescription1 IS NULL OR SubDescription1 = @SubDesc1* Study user manual about [Operator Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: What does you need when a variable is null - all records or only those where the field is null too?

Comment: some of the subdecriptions can be null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If NULL value of `@SubDesc1` means "return all records, do not apply filtering", then

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1   
WHERE Category = 'Category1'   
  AND [Description] ='ABC'   
  AND (    SubDescription1 = @SubDesc1
        OR @SubDesc1 IS NULL)
```

If NULL value of `@SubDesc1` means "return only those records, where the field IS NULL too", then

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1   
WHERE Category = 'Category1'   
  AND [Description] ='ABC'   
  AND (    SubDescription1 = @SubDesc1 
        OR COALESCE(@SubDesc1, SubDescription1) IS NULL )
```

Comment: Thanks, Akina. It works.